# When building Vim, how can I found out which missing dependencies caused which features to be disabled?

Tags: vim, build, configure

After running

```
$ ./configure --with-features=huge
```

Building, and then seeing some features disabled, e.g.

```
$ vim --version
...
-clientserver
...
```

I can look in `./src/config.log` and see which dependencies `configure` failed to find, but it does not tell me which of these caused the given feature (`clientserver`) to be disabled.

How can I find out which those are?

(Ideally I would like the build to *fail* if dependencies are missing but it seems that [is in development](http://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=13))

Answer (score 1):

That patch is included. The flag is `--enable-fail-if-missing`.

From `./configure --help`

```
  --enable-fail-if-missing    Fail if dependencies on additional features
     specified on the command line are missing.
```

This will only check to see if lua, perl, python, python3, Tcl, and Ruby can be configured.

---

In this case of `-clientserver` you need make sure you are building vim so that it can talk to X (`--with-x`). The client server feature uses the X Window Manager to communicate between sessions. I haven't looked but I imagine that vim won't enable it if it can't detect X.

---

Generally I don't think there is a way to get configure to fail currently.

Comment: +1 for useful advice, but this doesn't expose what's causing my vim to compile without `+clientserver`. I'm compiling on an Arch box. I added `--enable-fail-if-missing` to the `./configure` call in the `PKGBUILD` script and ran it, with no failures. When I install the compiled packages `vim --version` still says `-clientserver` despite that `--with-features=huge` is there too. I recently enabled `--enable-pythoninterp` in this way, and that worked.

Comment: @EmilLundberg (I'm not at a place where I can test this right now...) but why don't you just install the gvim package? That should have it included already.

Comment: Well, that actually worked. For some reason I didn't think of that. :) And apparently `--with-x=yes` was the magic word for enabling `+clientserver`.

Comment: @EmilLundberg Correct the way the client server works is by talking through X. (Which is why the gvim package already includes it)